# Views: Output field as a link with URL provided by another field?

Tags: views

So I have a content type with fields: image_field and url_field.

The view displays the field_image for all items. Now I want the user to click this image and go to the link in url_field on the same item.

If I try to write the output as a link it requires me set a path for field and it will always be the same URL for all items.

How do I tell it to display image_field with URL from it's own url_field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replacement tokens. URL field first in the list, hide the field, rewrite the image to render with a link, use the replacement token for the URL field as the link.

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuNkaGOwnR0

Comment: Ah. I didn't have the url_field on top of the list so that's why the replacement pattern wasn't there.